# How to update multiple charts in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

im researching d3.js over a week already, and I got stuck on one thing.
I created a donut chart, accroding to this:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/9/
```

this donut chart has an updae function that uses "arcTween" to update the chart:

```
function arcTween(a) {
var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
this._current = i(0);
return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
};
```

}

in this "arcTween" function, it uses arc function.
as it was witten for 1 donut chart, it was globaly declared.
since im using a multiple charts on page.
i wonder what is the way to do it.
i already tried to create this "arc" in an array, but it somehow doesnt work.

if there other way to achieve this, i would be happy to know.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the `arc` function as an argument?

Comment: it's tricky since the call to arcTween is by: .attrTween("d",arcTween) and somewhat, "arcTween" is read with a parameter named "a" which has endAngle, startAngle, Data and Value. so: 1. I dont know where this data came from as there is no parameter sent. 2. if im trying to pass a parameter like this : .attrTween("d",arcTween(parameter)) - then it breaks the pramater "a". ough !

Answer (score 0):

Here is Lars comments in Coffee-script
getTween returns the tween function with a unique arc

```
# Arc function
arc = (r) -> 
  return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(r*0.8).outerRadius(r)

# Closure for tween
getTween = (arc) ->
  tween  = (b) ->
    previous = if @previous? then @previous else 0
    i = d3.interpolate {amount: previous}, b
    @previous = b.data.amount
    return (t) -> arc i(t)

# Get tween function
tween = getTween arc(60)

# ENTER
pie.enter().append("svg:path")
   .attr("fill", core.getColor())
.transition()
   .ease("elastic")
   .duration(750)
   .attrTween("d",tween)
```